# Creating "imagePullSecret" to work with the deployment.yaml file which contains an image from the private repository

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have created a deployment yaml file with an image name with my private docker repository.
when running the command :

```
 kubectl get pods
```

I see that the status of the created pod from that deployment file is ImagePullBackOff. from what I have read it is because I am pulling the image from a private registry without imagePullSecret.

how do I create "imagePullSecret" as a yaml file to work with the deployment.yaml file which contains an image from the private repository? or is it a feild which should be part of the deployment file?

Comment: Imagepullsecret is a separate secret resource that needs to be created before or together with the deployment.

Comment: You can find lot of Infos here. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a field in spec of the pod called `imagePullSecrets`, whichi you could define with your deployment yaml:

```yaml
imagePullSecrets:
- name: registry-secret
```

Then you can define the missing  "imagePullSecret" as a yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: registry-secret
  namespace: xxx-namespace
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: UmVhbGx5IHJlYWxseSByZWVlZWVlZWVlZWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGx5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eXl5eSBsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbG9vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb29vb25ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubm5ubmdnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2dnZ2cgYXV0aCBrZXlzCg==
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

The data field `.dockerconfigjson` can be created from this [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#registry-secret-existing-credentials).

Answer (score 0):

First you create the imagePullSecret from your docker

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

Alternatively, you can create the imagePullSecret by providing the required arguments in the command line

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

Then use the imagePullSecret name in the pod manifest

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

Reference:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/